# Datalogics PDF Fill in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I'm trying to use the Datalogics PDF (https://api.datalogics-cloud.com/docs#fillform) to fill in a fillable pdf (made with adobe acrobat) in my rails app.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make the api call. I.e. I can't figure out where/how to put the parameters. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

One of the examples is using curl, so in a controller action I put `curl https://pdfprocess.datalogics.com/api/actions/render/pages --insecure --form 'application={"id": "xxxxx", "key": "xxxxxxx"}' --form input=@hello_world.pdf --form inputName=hello_world.pdf --output flattened.pdf` Which flattens the pdf hello_world (located in my rails root) into a pdf named flattened.pdf.

I'm not sure how to understand this code though.

Also, I've thought about instead of using the controller, use a form whose action is the url and has tags of the various fields, is that a valid possibility?

For the fill form, I'm attempting this curl command:

```
`curl https://pdfprocess.datalogics.com/api/actions/fill/form --insecure --form 'application={"id": "xxxxx", "key": "xxxxxx"}' --form input=@private/fillable/CG1218_6-95.pdf --form filename=@input.json --output flattened.pdf`
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far, and any errors that you are getting? what else you've tried etc??? (note: don't put it in the comments, edit your question and add it there because this stuff should be part of your question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTTP request to do this. I put together some code that you can see below. Your request will need need to be a multi part one, and that's why you will have to define a boundary. The request I have below is for the DocumentProperties service. You will need to modify it slightly to add the values for filling the form. Note that you will need to use "File.read()" to read the file with the values when passing it in.

You can see the relevant code below.

```
# Initialize a new HTTPS request object with our URL
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

##
# The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter, "boundary",
# which is used to specify the encapsulation boundary. The encapsulation boundary
# is defined as a line consisting entirely of two hyphen characters ("-", decimal code 45)
# followed by the boundary parameter value from the Content-Type header field.

BOUNDARY = 'BoundaryString'

# Initialize a new Post request
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request['content-type'] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=#{BOUNDARY}"


# Initialize a new helper array to aid us set up the post reuqest
post_body = []

# Add the application data, key and ID to the helper array
post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"application\"\r\n\r\n"
post_body << "{\"id\":\"#{app_id}\", \"key\":\"#{key}\"}"
post_body << "\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"


# Add the file Data to the helper array
post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"input\"; filename=\"#{File.basename(file)}\"\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n"

# Read the file data to the helper array
# Note that this reads the complete file in memory, and might not work well for large files
post_body << File.read(file)
post_body << "\r\n\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}--\r\n"

# Create the request body by joining all fields of the helper array together
request.body = post_body.join

# Submit the post request
response = http.request(request)
```